# Use previously-submitted values as default values in a GET-method form

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom form defined by the class below :

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {

    /**
     * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::getFormId()
     */
    public function getFormId(){
        return 'my_form_id';
    }

    /**
     * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::buildForm()
     */
    public function buildForm( array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state ){       
        $form['my_textfield'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('My textfield'),
            '#default_value' => 'I want the current value here !',
            '#description' => t('Description of my textfield.'),
            '#required' => true
        );

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::validateForm()
     */
    public function validateForm( array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state ){
        // Not implemented yet...
    }

    /**
     * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::submitForm()
     */
    public function submitForm( array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state ){
        // Not implemented yet...
    }

}
```

The form is then built in my page controller, using `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm()`. It overrides the form's `#method` attribute to `GET` because I want the field state to be present in the URL.

I'm looking for a correct Drupal-friendly way to assign the `#default_value` of my fields with the previously submitted state of the form.

**Edit:**

If I use a classic POST-method form and I add `$form_state->setRebuild();` in `::submitForm()`, I can get my values in `::buildForm()` using `$form_state->getValues()`. And the form is automatically rebuilt with the previously submitted values, without having to assign the default values programmatically...

---

**Could-be-related posts**

- [Access data from previously submitted values in buildForm in FormBase plugin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257550/access-data-from-previously-submitted-values-in-buildform-in-formbase-plugin/257568)
- [GET method form is not processed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226423/get-method-form-is-not-processed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final implementation...

**MyForm.php**

```
class MyForm extends FormBase {

    /**
     * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::getFormId()
     */
    public function getFormId(){
        return 'my_form_id';
    }

    /**
     * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::buildForm()
     */
    public function buildForm( array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state ){       
        $form['my_textfield'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('My textfield'),
            '#default_value' => 'I want the current value here !',
            '#description' => t('Description of my textfield.'),
            '#required' => true
        );

        $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
        $form['actions']['submit'] = [
           '#type' => 'submit',
           '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
           '#button_type' => 'primary',
        ];

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::submitForm()
     */
    public function submitForm( array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state ){
        // Nothing to do here...
    }

}
```

**MyController.php**

```
class MyController extends ControllerBase {

    public function index( Request $request ){

        // Here I can use $request->get('my_textfield') if needed

        $form_state = new FormState();
        $form_state->setRebuild(); // So that the form is rebuilt with previously submitted values
        $form_state->setMethod('GET'); // So that the form is submitted via GET method (URL)

        return \Drupal::formBuilder()->buildForm( '\Drupal\my_module\Form\MyForm', $form_state );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set query parameters on submit and then you can fetch them and use as default values.

**1] Redirect on submit**

```
$form_state->setRedirect($route_name, $route_parameters, $options);
```

**2] Fetch query parameters**

```
$params = \Drupal::request()->query->all();
```

Comment: Why the redirection ?

Comment: I thought you want to add query parameters to the current url. It is a way to refresh the current page and append submitted values as query parameters.

The solution you found (setRebuild) is very simple and practical though.